# Run barcodescanner for phonegap inside a page (not fullscreen)

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've been using the BarcodeScanner plugin to experiment with QR code scanning in phonegap and that seems to be working.

I've used this sample: https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeDemo

However, I'd like the barcodescanner to show up inside a page at let's say 25% of the screen width instead of it showing up fullscreen. Is that something that can be done with phonegap and the barcodescanner? I'd also like to use the front camera and not the back camera.

More specifically, I'd like to implement the scanner inside an ipad app at around 25% of the screen while the rest of the app shows different content. I'm hoping to do this with Phonegap as this is the only part where my app needs to communicate with the camera, the rest can be purely web based.

Comment: This is possible but you would have to write your own plugin (native code) that implements the scanner the way you have described. There is not a way to do this without writing native code.

Comment: Ok that makes sense (and sucks for me). Can I mark your comment as an answer somehow? I'll probably skip phonegap and use titanium or go native to build this app.

Comment: I'll make answer with more details and add it here

Answer (score 0):

The Scandit Barcode Scanner plugin supports an in-app-view:

[Scandit Barcode Scanner plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aplimovil-plugin-scandit)

It's not free, but works very well.